# Is it possible to run adobe master collection cs6 in ubuntu

Tags: wine

I do video editing, music making, web design, and photo editing. I don't want to have to use another application to do what I can get from Adobe. I also want to switch to Ubuntu. I have windows 8 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have 2 options on doing that.  The first option is using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).  Wine allows you to run Windows applications under Ubuntu.

The second option is by using virtual machines.  A virtual machine is a separate and independent software instance that includes a full copy of an operating system and application software.  You can have more that on VM running at the same time depending on your hardware configuration.

You can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), which is free, or [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/), which is also free.  VMWare offers a paid program called [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/).