# Run Adobe CS6 from Win7 install in dual-boot?

Tags: dual-boot, wine, adobe

I've got a windows machine and recently decided to add a second hard drive with Xubuntu to run a dual-boot setup. I already have Adobe Master Collection CS 6 installed on my windows HD. Is there a way for me to run CS 6 applications in Xubuntu, from where they currently reside on the other HD? The entire Win7 HD is accessible to browse in Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the best way to do this is using Wine. And you have most of the work done because most of the bugs appear during the installation. Once you have the program ready to run it's only a matter of getting the configuration right... 
You can install wine just by running:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

(replace apt-get with aptitude if needed, I don't remember the package manager of Xubuntu)
Here is the official documentation of Wine Database: 
http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607 
Note: the documentation says it's only been tested on Ubuntu 12.10 Kubuntu and some older version but I don't think there will be any difference.
Once you configured it as the documentation says just go to the main .exe (the one that you 'd use to launch it on windows), right click it and select "Open with Wine". This should start the program.
I have tested this with several programs and it works fine
Also you may need to install some .dll files. You can use winetricks for this

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

To use this you can run the .exe file from the terminal to see the error that it may display. To do this you can enter this command:

```
wine /route/Program.exe
```

Or you can cd to route and run:

```
wine Program.exe
```

Google the name of the dll and once you 've found the library for winetricks you can do:

```
winetricks dlls dll_name
```

Replacing dll_name for the name of the dll found.
Finally you can use the command

```
winecfg
```

To set up the details of wine configuration in a more friendly enviroment.
Hope this was useful and sorry about my english :D

Edit:
I 've also found some issues with the License but I can run any program that doesn't need a license. Maybe you should install all CS6 again using wine (in my personal experience this usually brings lots of bugs).
Sadly I have no programs with original license to try this out.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't just re run the installed exe from that location.

You need to install them in linux again. You can take help of **`wine`**. 
Though there is several restriction and the product may not run correctly to full extent.

Please see http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=category&iId=29&sAction=view&sTitle=Browse+Applications for know the compatibility.

Related question : [Is it possible to run adobe master collection cs6 in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291648/is-it-possible-to-run-adobe-master-collection-cs6-in-ubuntu)